# How can I uninstall skype for business?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, skype, office365, skype-for-business

I would like to keep "normal" Skype installed.

I have seen many options for "disabling" it such that it doesn't start online, but is there any way to simply uninstall it completely?

edit: thanks to The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I have stopped it from auto-starting, but I will keep this question open as I would still like to be notified if anyone does come up with a solution for a full uninstall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding that it is possible to delete/uninstall Skype using the ODT tool. 
(source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_otherapps-mso_win10-msoversion_other/uninstall-skype-for-business-win-10-office-2016/9dc59f38-b63b-4532-8cff-5a9f9e67cc08?auth=1] )

> Download the Office 2016 Deployment Tool from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49117).
>
> Run the downloaded .exe executable file.
>
> Select a local folder (for example C:\ODT2016) and extract the files to that folder.
>
> You will get two files, setup.exe and configuration.xml.
>
> Open "configuration.xml" in a text editor (like notepad).
>       Replace the complete content of the configuration.xml with the following lines:
>
> ```
> <Configuration>
>   <Add SourcePath="C:\ODT2016" OfficeClientEdition="32">
>     <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
>       <Language ID="en-us" />
>       <ExcludeApp ID="Lync" />
>     </Product>
>   </Add>
>   <Display Level="Full" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />  
> </Configuration>
> ```
>
> Change `OfficeClientEdition="32"` to `OfficeClientEdition="64"` if you are on a 64-bit system.
>
> Save the changes and close your text editor.
>
> Open a 'Command Prompt window' as administrator.
>
> At the command prompt, type: (assuming that you extracted the files to "C:\ODT2016")
>
> ```
> cd c:\ODT2016
> ```
>
> Next, enter the following command:
>
> ```
> setup.exe /download configuration.xml
> ```
>
> Wait for the prompt to return. (Note that It may take a while for this command to complete).
>      Enter the following command:
>
> ```
> setup.exe /configure configuration.xml
> ```
>
> Confirm to close 'Skype for Business' when asked.
>      Wait for the setup to finish.
>      Close the 'Command Prompt window'.
>      Remove the folder where you extracted the files.
>      Restart your computer to test the result.
>
> For me this worked like a charm and Skype for Business was finally gone from my system.
>
> Also worth noting is that all of the remaining Office applications still work just fine. The procedure has had no impact of any of their settings.

Comment: I didn't get two files, I got four files of which three XML files: `configuration-Office365-x64.xml`, `configuration-Office365-x86.xml` and `configuration-Office2019Enterprise.xml`. Which one should I use?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Depends of which version you have installed. if its 32-bit go for x-86.xml or x-64.xml for 64-bit. replace the configuration.xml with the one you selected

Answer (score 19):

**Skype for Business** (*Lync*) is a part of **MS Office** now.

> You can only remove it if you have installed a **MSI based Office**,
>   with **Click-to-Run** version installed, all you can do is disable.

If you have MSI based Office installed, go to **appwiz.cpl** & choose to change to remove Skype For Business.

[image]

If you have Click-to-Run based Office installed, you can only disable it from auto-starting by unchecking "**Automatically start the app when I log on to Windows**" or using advanced tools like [Autoruns](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/Autoruns.zip) for Windows from sysinternals

[image]

[Source 1](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Completely-Uninstall-Skype-For-Business/td-p/3961381) & [Source 2](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/How-to-complete-remove-Skype-for-Business-from-Windows-10/td-p/4122751)

Comment: Well darn, I had a "click to run" version of 365

Comment: I've had it disabled for some time now, saw it in months today after this question